# Compute the smallest integer greater than $\sum_{d\mid 2016}\sum_{m\mid\mid d}\frac{1}{m}.$

Tags: number-theory

> Given two positive integers $m$ and $n$, we say that $m\mid\mid n$ if $m\mid n$ and $\gcd(m,\, n/m)=1$. Compute the smallest integer greater than
>   $$\sum_{d\mid 2016}\sum_{m\mid\mid d}\frac{1}{m}.$$

Solution:

Let $d=\prod p_i^{e_i}$; then $\sum_{m\mid \mid d} \frac{1}{m}=\prod (1+\frac{1}{p_i^{e_i}})$. Thus, the answer is the ceiling of $$\left(1+\sum_{d=1}^5 1+\frac{1}{2^d}\right)\left(1+\sum_{d=1}^2 1+\frac{1}{3^d}\right)\left(1+\sum_{d=1}^1 +\frac{1}{7^d}\right).$$

This solution isn't explained very well. It seems very related to the Euler totient function's $\phi(n) = \prod n(1+\dfrac{1}{p_i})$, but I am not sure if it is. How does this give the answer?

Comment: That doesn't work unless you know something about $\sum_{m\mid\mid d} \frac{1}{m}$ being multiplicative.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Do you mean the solution?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why that is obvious at all.

Comment: Never mind, I just realized why it is multiplicative.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How does it being multiplicative make it work?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: *I just realized why it is multiplicative* - Care to share your findings with the rest of us ?

Comment: @Lucian What does the notation $\left(1+\sum_{d=1}^1 +\frac{1}{7^d}\right)$ mean? Shouldn't there be a $1$ in there?